# Keep running into an issue where GitHub will not follow links, even though they are set up

Tags: html, github

So, when i was working on GitHub, trying to set up a website on gitHub domains, it won't follow links. Here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form action="homepage.html" method="post"> 
  <div class="imgcontainer">
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
    <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name = "uname" required>

    <label for="psw"></label><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder = "Enter Password" name="psw" required>

    <button onclick="logIn" type="submit"></button>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
    <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
    <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="petonstepens.github.io/cookies/forgotPassword.html">password?</a></span>
    <span class="create">No Account? <a href="petonstepens.github.io/cookies/createAccount.html">Create One</a></span>
  </div>

</form>

<style>
    form {
        border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
    }

    input[type=text], input[type=password] {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    button {
        background-color: #04AA6D;
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 100%;
    }

    button:hover {
        opacity: 0.80;
    }

    .cancelbtn {
        width: auto;
        padding: 10px 18px;
        background-color: #f44336;
    }

    .container {
        padding: 16px;
    }

    span.psw {
        float: right;
        padding-top: 16px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
        span.psw {
            display: block;
            float: none;
        }

        .cancelbtn {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
</style>
<script>
    function logIn() {
        document.getElementById("submit").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("uname", "psw");
    }
</script>
```

But when I run the website in Git Hub, the links will not go though, and hovering over then says that they are just files on my computer. Also, when I put in an email and password and hit the green bar, it says 405 Not Allowed. Any Ideas?

I have gone through and renamed a lot of the files and edited the links, but still nothing works. I was hoping that that would fix the issue, but it just sits there.

Answer (score 0):

1. The "405 Not Allowed" is because you can't `POST` to GitHub Pages. (The server disallows POST; local files "allow" POST, but don't really do anything with the POSTed data.) Change `<form action="homepage.html" method="post">` to just `<form action="homepage.html">` to use a GET request (but note that the data you enter will be visible in the query string, e.g. `/homepage.html?uname=peton&psw=supersecret`).
2. `petonstepens.github.io/cookies/forgotPassword.html` is a relative URL to a file in a directory `petonstepens.github.io/cookies` (simplified a bit); you'll want `://petonstepens.github.io/cookies/forgotPassword.html` for a protocol-relative URL, but really, you'd probably want just `cookies/forgotPassword.html` if this is your `index.html`.

Comment: While attempting to use FormSubmit, it tells me that i need the `POST` attribute.

Comment: @peton https://formsubmit.co/ ? Sure, but then you'll also need that `action=""` they tell you to use (which does allow POST).